# What is the difference between awarded and rewarded

Tags: word-usage, difference

I want to know what is the difference between awarded and rewarded.

sentence with awarded:

**No marks will be *awarded* if the student cheats in the examination**

sentence with rewarded:

**He *rewarded* the dog with a treat**

Comment: FWIW: Award is usually a serious achievement, reward is not that serious.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip, perhaps you can answer the question here.

Comment: An _award_ is something given in formal recognition of an achievement. A _reward_ is a present to thank someone for a favour, whether it's a dog doing a trick or the finder of valuable lost property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at a few references, I would most agree with this comparison:
[Difference between Award and Reward](https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-award-and-reward.html)

> The reward is the benefit (monetary or otherwise) given to an individual for his hard work to achieve something.
>
> The award is a recognition which is conferred to individuals or an organization for achieving something great.

They specifically point out these differences:

1. **Greatness** - awards are for rare achievements | rewards are for any effort
2. **Demonstration** - awards are public | rewards are private
3. **Decided By** - awards are decided by a group | rewards are decided by an individual
4. **Type** - awards are usually from a competition | rewards can be from simple tasks

---

Taking this to explain usage in your specific examples:

> No marks will be awarded if the student cheats in the examination

Award is used there because it is more serious, even if it is one test or exam. The marks are decided by an educational institution and made public.

> He rewarded the dog with a treat

Reward is used there because it is for a simple task. The dog did something good, so it was given something in return without needing to announce it to others.